# How to use chrome to login to same site twice with different credentials?

Tags: google-chrome, authentication

Even though chrome runs tabs as different processes it appears to not support this... any ideas or documentation I might have missed?

Answer (score 1):

Try two different incognito windows.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stay logged in for a period of time, the best thing to do is to create a new profile for each set of credentials. Click the face icon in the top right-hand corner and select "new user."

[image: creating a new profile]

If you just want to log-in with different credentials once, it might be easier to use incognito mode, as rmmh said.